# Multiple association on same entity with hibernate Criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, left-join, criteria

I would like to use this query in Hibernate criteria

```
SELECT a.a_id, b.b_id, b.b_description, sum(c1.c_score) AS score1, sum(c2.c_score) AS score2
FROM b, a, d, c

LEFT OUTER JOIN c AS c1 ON c1.c_id = c.c_id AND c1.c_comment = 'good'
LEFT OUTER JOIN c AS c2 ON c2.c_id = c.c_id AND c2.c_comment = 'nogood'

WHERE b.b_Id = d.d_id
AND d.d_id = c.c_id
AND c.c_foreignkey_a_id = a.a_id

GROUP BY a.a_id, b.b_id, b.b_description
```

My problem, in this case, is the 2 associations on the same entity ( C => C1 / C => C2).

And I want to know if there is a way to do this with criteria ?

Thanks ! - EZ

Comment: Hi, are you in pure Hibernate or with JPA ?

Comment: Hi, I'm in pure Hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a serious limitation when using Hibernate Criteria ([Now Deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/apb.html)).

You can try one the two "solutions" :

- You can map the association twice ( in read only) ... not really clean
- You can try to express you request with criteria subqueries. [Example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It's possible to have more precision for the 2nd solution ?

Comment: There are examples here :  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries

Comment: i use an other methods now, but thank for your help !